# rails SQlite 3: Cant open the connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have existing rails project with PostgreSQL DB. When I am running the same in my local machine I am receiving SQLite exception.

But my database.yml configured with postgres adapter only.

Here is the exception:

SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file

`database.yml`

postgres: &postgres
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  min_messages: warning

development:
  <<: *postgres
  database: dev_development
  username: <%= ENV['PG_USER'] || 'postgres' %>
  password: <%= ENV['PG_PASSWORD'] || 'postgres' %>

test:
  <<: *postgres
  database: dev_test
  username: <%= ENV['PG_USER'] || 'postgres' %>
  password: <%= ENV['PG_PASSWORD'] %>

Comment: Update question with exception you are getting on console.

Comment: Update question with `database.yml`

Comment: Wondering here is, My app db configurations pointing to POstgres but I am getting exception on SQLite.

Comment: Updated with error and database.yml entries

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have an environment variable set (DATABASE_URL) that is overriding your database.yml file? Look at this for more info: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

If that's not it, is it possible you recently changed your database.yml file and haven't restarted the server?